# sqlalchemy SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
uid = Column(String(32), primary_key= True, ForeignKey("ques_bank.uid"), auto_increment = False)
```

gives me a `SyntaxError`:

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

I'm new at this, so need help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a non-keyword argument after a keyword argument. Do you know what those terms mean?

Comment: Did you try a Google search for _the exact title of your question_?

Comment: means it is treating foreignKey as non-keyword but in my knowledge foreignkey is a keyword in sql!!

Comment: And yeah i tried google search but i didn't find it in sqlalchemy context..so i post it and that's why it is not duplicate

Comment: If you didn't find results, it means you didn't look at any of them, because all of the top results would have answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`uid = Column(String(32), ForeignKey("ques_bank.uid"), primary_key= True, auto_increment = False)`

You should read up on keyword arguments in Python python keyword arguments order.

Let us say that you have a function:

`def fn(a,b=1,x=2,d=6,e=5): return 2`

If you call the function like this: `fn(1,2,3)`, then `a=1`, `b=2`, and `x=3`. However, if you say, `fn(2, e=1, 5)`, then what does 5 get assigned to? This is why you cannot call functions with keyword arguments before non-keyword arguments ....

Comment: Ok, but why does this (presumably) work when OP's code didn't?

Comment: but now showing NameError: name 'ForeignKey' is not defined

Comment: and yeah why does this work??

Comment: I have updated my answer. I assume you forgot to import `ForeignKey`. Please import that before you run the program